# JQuery: Fixing table column and row is stuttering on scroll on Mac OS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, macos

So I have tried to fix left column and upper row on scroll using jQuery. The problem is that on scroll they are stuttering on Mac OS on all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) while on other OSes it works correctly. Is there something that I need to add in order for it to be cross-platform?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x54anbfp/)

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $("#table-div").scroll (function() {
        var scrlTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        var scrlLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();
        $(".big").each (function() {
            $(this).css ({
                'margin-left': scrlLeft,
                left: scrlLeft
            });
        });
        $(".group").each (function() {
            $(this).css ({
                left: scrlLeft
            });
        });
        $(".item").each (function() {
            $(this).css ({
                top: scrlTop
            });
        });
        $("#top-left").css ({
            top: scrlTop,
            left: scrlLeft
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I do not see any UI glitches on OSX Sierra.

Comment: This is working fine for me as well in Firefox on Sierra.